# Syntax error in parsing a simple json with quotes?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a Json which contains a double quotes string in JavaScript using Json2.js as shown below.

```
<script src="Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        try {
            var inv = JSON.parse('{"Items":[{"Quantity":1,"Description":"Width : 16\" Asd","Price":49.17,"IsEditable":false}],"Vat":20.00,"Delivery":0}');
            console.log(inv.Vat);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

</script>
```

But I am getting a syntax error in parsing. Am i missing something here?

Comment: If you've found an answer to your question helped solve your probmem, please accept it by clicking the tick next to the answer. It will help build your reputation and show in your profile box encouraging answers to any new questions.

Answer (score 3):

The slash character in `"Width : 16\"` is treated as escaping the `"` character in the JavaScript string. Since the string is delimited by single quotes, that makes no difference and is th same as `"Width : 16"`.

In order to have a JSON escaped quote character inside a JavaScript string literal, you need to escape the escape.

```
"Width : 16\\"
```

You would probably be better off just having a JS object literal instead of a string of JSON that you immediately parse:

```
var inv = {"Items":[{"Quantity":1,"Description":"Width : 16\" Asd","Price":49.17,"IsEditable":false}],"Vat":20.00,"Delivery":0};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\"` will be converted to `"` by JavaScript already when parsing the string.

To make it pass a `\"` to JSON,  you should use `\\"`. That way, the parsed string is `\"` and this will parse correctly in turn at `JSON.parse`.